Can i add formula in Location field?
Can i add formula in Location field ?
I want to add formula for example sin(30 degree) * 10 in Location field. How can I do?


Where does “degree” come from?

You actually want radians in the sin function, not degrees.
Just click in the field then type sin(radians(30)) + 10, then press Enter.
Think of the field text input as an ultra-compact python interpreter where you can type and evaluate a single expression.
